# Xcode __pthread_kill + 20

Tags: c++, c, xcode, console-application

I am trying to run simple command line application with large array, it works if I try looping through 30 rows of the array, but when I increase it to 1000 it crashes, showing (lldb) in the console. Under thread 1 I have __pthread_kill , __stack_chk_fail .  My code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


int i;
int j;
int x;


int mains [2][50]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
    31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50};
int stars [2][11]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};

int results [1000][7]={

    {27,29,37,39,49,2,4}, //03.04.2015

    {8,20,24,28,49,8,9},

 // rest of array not relevant to the problem

    {16,29,32,36,41,7,9},

};



for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        for (x=0; x<51; x++)
        {
            if (results[i][j]==mains[0][x])
            {
                mains[1][x]++;
            }
        }

    }
}

for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    for (j=5; j<7; j++)
    {
        for (x=0; x<12; x++)
        {
            if (results[i][j]==stars[0][x])
            {
                stars[1][x]++;
            }
        }

    }
}



for (i=0; i<49; i++)      //array sorting
{
    for (j=i+1; j<50; j++)
    {
        if (mains[1][i]>mains[1][j])
        {
            std::swap(mains[0][i],mains[0][j]);
            std::swap(mains[1][i],mains[1][j]);            }
    }

}

for (i=0; i<10; i++)      //array sorting
{
    for (j=i+1; j<11; j++)
    {
        if (stars[1][i]>stars[1][j])
        {
            std::swap(stars[0][i],stars[0][j]);
            std::swap(stars[1][i],stars[1][j]);            }
    }

}




printf("Mains        Stars:\n\n");
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    printf("%d ",mains[0][i]);
}

for (i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    printf("%d ",stars[0][i]);
}


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (x=0; x<51; x++)
              ^^^^
    {
        if (results[i][j]==mains[0][x])
                                   ^^^
```

So, `x` goes from 0 to 50 inclusive. That means `mains[0]` has to have 51 elements.

(If you don't see why, imagine if `x` went from 0 to `4` inclusive. That would mean you need `5` elements, `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. So if you iterate from 0 to `n` inclusive, you need `n+1` elements.)

```
int mains [2][50]={1,2,3,
              ^^
```

Oops, it only has 50.

Comment: That probably wouldn't cause a the failure he's seeing as that would probably just overwrite the adjacent `stars` local variable.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It depends on the memory layout, which we don't know. The array could abut unallocated space.

Comment: Possible, but it's not likely at all.  He's only overrunning by one, and there are local variables defined both before and after the array he's overrunning.  Given that he didn't report running out of stack space with it set to 30 rows but did when he set it to 1000 rows, and he didn't say row length changed from 50, I'd bet a good bit of coin that that overrun didn't cause blowing out the stack.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Looking more closely at it, I suspect you're right.

Answer (score 0):

When you increased the size of your local variable, you ran out of stack space:

http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/libc---stack-chk-fail-1.html

> __stack_chk_fail -- terminate a function in case of stack overflow